# AdvancedFirewall: Adding a Program to the Inbound Rules

Tags: windows, firewall

I am writing an application that contains a web server running on port 50000. On Windows 7, short of turning the firewall off completely, I am having trouble configuring the firewall to allow other computers on the same private LAN to connect to the server. Simply adding the program to the allowed programs list doesn't seem to work. The network connection is set to be a "Home" network (but I am not using HomeGroup networking). Can anyone suggest where I should be looking to troubleshoot this?

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should create an inbound port rule (instead of a program rule) on the web server that allows incoming traffic to connect to the web server on port 50000.